# CASE statement that outputs adjacent column if having a match (SQL)

Tags: sql, mysql, case

I'm writing a SQL query and would like to create a CASE statement that performs the following:

- For every `Id`, I should take the **max year** from within two columns: `End_Year` and `Complete_Year`, and
- Match that **max year** to the `Country_Code` that corresponds to it from the table, from either `End_Year` or `Complete_Year`
- Would like to do this inside a CASE statement/s due to certain technical limitations. It's pretty complicated :/

The table looks like this:

| Id | Country_Code | End_Year | Complete_Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | USA | 2022 | 2023 |
| 101 | ARG | 2021 | 2022 |
| 102 | CAN | 2026 | 2025 |
| 102 | CAN | 2022 | 2023 |

The output I would want is:

| Id | Final_Country_Code | Final_Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | USA | 2023 |
| 102 | CAN | 2026 |

I currently managed to get the `final_year` but not the `country_code` that matches the maximum end_year/complete_year for each id:

```
SELECT
id,
MAX(CASE WHEN (end_year >= complete_year) THEN end_year ELSE complete_year END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS final_year

FROM
sample_table
```

Comment: Ok and what have you tried so far

Comment: What's the output if USA and ARG has the same max year?

Comment: @flyingfox I checked the data and there were no instances of such. So for purposes of the logic, then maybe the first one (USA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some options how to do this...

Let's first say we can use `GREATEST` to get the greater of the two years.

Then we can for example `JOIN` the table to itself and check there is no other row for the same id which has a greater year.

I commented the steps in the query:

```
SELECT 
  main.id, main.country_code, 
  GREATEST(main.end_year, main.complete_year) AS finalYear # take the max of the two years
FROM yourtable main
  LEFT JOIN yourtable sub # self JOIN on the id
    ON main.id = sub.id 
    AND GREATEST(main.end_year, main.complete_year) < # compare the current year to other years of the same id
        GREATEST(sub.end_year, sub.complete_year)
  WHERE sub.id is NULL; # check there is no greater year for the current id
```

Another option to get the desired result is to use a `CTE`.

First we take every id with its latest year:

```
SELECT
  id, MAX(GREATEST(end_year, complete_year)) AS finalYear
FROM yourtable
  GROUP BY id;
```

Then we use `IN` or `JOIN` to check which rows of the table have both the correct id and year.

Here with `IN`:

```
WITH maxData AS 
  (SELECT
    id, MAX(GREATEST(end_year, complete_year)) AS finalYear
  FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY id)
SELECT
  id, country_code, GREATEST(end_year, complete_year) AS finalYear
FROM yourtable
  WHERE (id, GREATEST(end_year, complete_year)) 
    IN (SELECT id, finalYear FROM maxData);
```

Here with `JOIN`:

```
WITH maxData AS 
  (SELECT
    id, MAX(GREATEST(end_year, complete_year)) AS finalYear
  FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY id)
SELECT
  y.id, y.country_code, GREATEST(y.end_year, y.complete_year) AS finalYear
FROM yourtable y 
INNER JOIN maxData d 
  ON y.id = d.id 
  AND GREATEST(y.end_year, y.complete_year) = d.finalYear;
```

It's hard to say which is the best approach and if it really makes an important difference. I think the option to use a `CTE` is more readable, but that's just my "taste".

Try out the above queries on this [fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/Cp0g84sv)